# what's wrong with linking against SuiteSparse's libldl?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to compile this simple (and useless) C++ program with g++ (GCC version 4.8.3), and I'm having problems when linking against a library from SuiteSparse:

```
#include "ldl.h"

int main() {
  int a = 3;
  ldl_symbolic(a, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

When I launch

```
g++ -c -I<path>/LDL/Include -I<path>/SuiteSparse_config main.cpp
g++ -L<path>/LDL/Lib main.o -lldl
```

The same happens if the for linking I use gcc instead of g++:

```
gcc -L<path>/LDL/Lib main.o -lldl
```

I get this error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ldl_symbolic(int, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if I inspect libldl.a with nm it looks like the symbol is present in the static library:

```
ldl.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000560 T ldl_dsolve
00000000000004e0 T ldl_lsolve
0000000000000610 T ldl_ltsolve
0000000000000180 T ldl_numeric
00000000000006a0 T ldl_perm
00000000000006d0 T ldl_permt
0000000000000000 T ldl_symbolic
00000000000007b0 T ldl_valid_matrix
0000000000000700 T ldl_valid_perm
                 U memset

ldll.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000480 T ldl_l_dsolve
0000000000000420 T ldl_l_lsolve
0000000000000530 T ldl_l_ltsolve
0000000000000160 T ldl_l_numeric
00000000000005b0 T ldl_l_perm
00000000000005e0 T ldl_l_permt
0000000000000000 T ldl_l_symbolic
00000000000006c0 T ldl_l_valid_matrix
0000000000000610 T ldl_l_valid_perm
                 U memset
```

Any idea on when such a problem may occur?

Comment: Did you try compiling and linking using `gcc` instead of `g++`?

Comment: yes, same thing (I edited the question, thanks)

Comment: `main.cpp` should also be compiled using `gcc`, or wrap the header in a `extern "C" {}` clause.

Comment: it was that. many, many thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: I'm marking your question as a duplicate, because I've already given the answer once there. Hope that's OK for you.